# Textboxes in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

Do you guys know how to put a lot of textboxes, one after the other inside of a scrollview creating like a infinity effect for entering a non defined quantity of numbers and then put them in an array?

Comment: Depends entirely on the platform you are developing for.

Answer (score 1):

If this is WinForms, add a `FlowLayoutPanel` to your form in the designer, then from code you can add `NumericUpDown` controls for validated entry of numbers:

```
class InfinityForm : Form {

    private FlowLayoutPanel _panel;

    public InfinityForm() {

        _panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        this.Controls.Add( _panel );
        _panel.Dock = Dock.Fill;
    }

    public override void OnLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            NumericUpDown editor = new NumericUpDown();
            editor.Controls.Add( editor );
        }
    }
}
```

I'm missing some logic here and setting display attributes on the controls, but you get the general idea.

The advantage of `FlowLayoutPanel` is that it manages the layout of the controls for you, so you don't need to calculate and set `.Location` and `.Size` properties yourself.

Comment: Nice. I'd expect some sort of "on text changed" handler to add more textboxes for "infinite" effect, but that should be enough to get one started.